# Does notification always show when service is running?

Tags: java, android, service, notifications

I have an app that uses a service. When the service is destroyed a notification is created from the ondestroyed method. In android version 9 after starting the service, a notification appears, in some instances, for example on one occasion after 3 hours the notification disappeared after the service was started and it did not bring the notification for ondestroyed, instead the notification for ondestroyed came after 5 hours of the service's notification disappearing. Am trying to understand this behavior, does this mean that a notification will not always appear when a foreground service is running?

Comment: 1.) Under what conditions (specifically) is the `Service` destroyed? (What _triggers_ the destruction?) 2.) How do you know the `Service` is not crashing or being preemptively terminated after 3 hours? 3.) How do you know the `Service` is not being re-created in the interim 5 hour period?

Comment: No condition would call for destruction of service. It is meant to work continuously until the user's device destroys it

Comment: Am not sure as to how I would know (3),if it stops and is recreated, shouldn't I still receive a notification that it was destroyed?

Comment: If your `Service` is truly a foreground service, and the notification associated with that service disappears, then your service has either A.) crashed or B.) been preemptively terminated. In either case, `onDestroy()` will not be called.

Comment: Okay, is there a way to know how it crashed or preemptively terminated and find a way to fix it?

Comment: Crashed: Look at your logcat when the notification disappears. Preemptively terminated: This is unlikely, for a foreground service, and will only happen if the device is under severe memory pressure.

Comment: Ohh, okay I found the reason, you were right it crashed. If I may ask would you know where in the service class one should put 'Androidthreetenbp.init(this)'? Am using Jake Wharton.threetenabp in my project and am using the library in service class

Comment: Should it be put in onstartcommand or the method in the service class where it's being used?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what that is. You may want to ask a separate question.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much for your help though